# How to fire a javascript event using Python

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium

I'm trying to create a Python script that navigates to the Facebook marketplace and inputs the Min and Max price. I can't figure out how to fire the java script event to update the page with the items within the Min/Max price range. Any help would be appreciated

````
```
From selenium import webdriver

usr = "username"
pwd = "password"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\webdriver\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get('https://www.facebook.com')
username_box = driver.find_element_by_id('email') 
username_box.send_keys(usr) 
password_box = driver.find_element_by_id('pass') 
password_box.send_keys(pwd)
login_box = driver.find_element_by_id('loginbutton') 
login_box.click() 

driver.get('https://www.facebook.com/marketplace/toronto/vehicles/')

elem = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('_58al')
elem[0].send_keys("5000")
elem[1].send_keys("10000")
```
````

Comment: This can be done using page reloading, say every 1 minute. Or using ajax with a timer, to check periodically for updates, or websockets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of waiting for the event to trigger upon submitting your values, you could directly append your values to the URI and navigate with `driver.get()` knowing with confidence the page will display your results :)

```
https://www.facebook.com/marketplace/[randomints]/?minPrice=100&maxPrice=200
```

However, if you'd like to continue with submitting values you could consider using `click()` on  the following class name `_78o5` which at a glance, does seem to fire off the refresh event.